# Problem while launching simple Gnome extension on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

When i launch the extension.js demo file that is provided by Gnome at https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html#a-working-extension
I get this error :

> const St = imports.gi.St;
> ReferenceError: imports is not defined

here is the code :

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

const ExtensionUtils = imports.misc.extensionUtils;
const Me = ExtensionUtils.getCurrentExtension();
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const PanelMenu = imports.ui.panelMenu;


class Extension {
    constructor() {
        this._indicator = null;
    }

    enable() {
        log(`enabling ${Me.metadata.name}`);

        let indicatorName = `${Me.metadata.name} Indicator`;

        // Create a panel button
        this._indicator = new PanelMenu.Button(0.0, indicatorName, false);

        // Add an icon
        let icon = new St.Icon({
            gicon: new Gio.ThemedIcon({name: 'face-laugh-symbolic'}),
            style_class: 'system-status-icon'
        });
        this._indicator.add_child(icon);

        // `Main.panel` is the actual panel you see at the top of the screen,
        // not a class constructor.
        Main.panel.addToStatusArea(indicatorName, this._indicator);
    }

    // REMINDER: It's required for extensions to clean up after themselves when
    // they are disabled. This is required for approval during review!
    disable() {
        log(`disabling ${Me.metadata.name}`);

        this._indicator.destroy();
        this._indicator = null;
    }
}


function init() {
    log(`initializing ${Me.metadata.name}`);

    return new Extension();
}
```

I searched online but didn't find any solution for my problem.

Comment: What is inside `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/example@shell.gnome.org/` folder? list the files and the file content.

Comment: i just found a solution but thanks anyway